# Flask SQLAlchemy pagination error

Tags: python, pagination, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have this code and the `all()` method and every other method works on this and I have looked all over and I could that the method `paginate()` works on `BaseQuery` which is also `Query`

```
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
@app.route('/blog')
@app.route('/index/<int:page>')
def index(page = 1):
    posts = db.session.query(models.Post).paginate(page, RESULTS_PER_PAGE, False)
return render_template('index.html', title="Home", posts=posts)
```

but this gives me the error `AttributeError: 'Query' object has no attribute 'paginate'`
I've looked everywhere and I can't find any solution to this.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

From your question...

```
that the method paginate() works on BaseQuery which is also Query
```

I think this is where you're being confused. "Query" refers to the SQLAlchemy [`Query`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/query.html#the-query-object) object. "BaseQuery" refers to the Flask-SQLALchemy [`BaseQuery`](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/api.html#flask.ext.sqlalchemy.BaseQuery) object, which is a  subclass of `Query`. This subclass includes helpers such as [`first_or_404()`](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/api.html#flask.ext.sqlalchemy.BaseQuery.first_or_404) and [`paginate()`](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/api.html#flask.ext.sqlalchemy.BaseQuery.paginate). However, this means that a `Query` object does NOT have the `paginate()` function. How you actually build the object you are calling your "Query" object depends on whether you are dealing with a `Query` or `BaseQuery` object.

In this code, you are getting the SQLAlchemy `Query` object, which results in an error:

```
db.session.query(models.Post).paginate(...)
```

If you use the following code, you get the pagination you're looking for, because you are dealing with a `BaseQuery` object (from Flask-SQLAlchemy) rather than a `Query` object (from SQLAlchemy).

```
models.Post.query.paginate(...)
```

Comment: Thanks this worked! I was indeed getting confused between the two. This cleared it up for me :)